# multiple custom modules configuration not visible in backend

Tags: magento-1.8, database, theme, configuration

We installed Theme files & sample database, according to theme demo link it should display multiple modules features [`slider, displaying New products , Featured products` ]  under configuration as below image.

but that configuation part is not visible. is there any way  i can display that configuration part in admin with help of source code as it contains all module code related to slider, new products ..etc....

`app/code/local/Magentothem/` - Newproductslider ,Bannerslider ..etc

`app/design/frontend/default/ma_aries_man/template/magentothem/newproducts/newproductslider.phtml`

`app/design/frontend/default/ma_aries_man/template/magentothem/featuredproducts/featuredproductslider.phtml`  ..etc

[image]

EDit -app/code/local/Magentothem/Newproductslider/etc/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <magentothem translate="label" module="newproductslider">
            <label>Magentothem</label>
            <sort_order>205</sort_order>
        </magentothem>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <newproductslider translate="label" module="newproductslider">
            <label>New Product Slider</label>
            <tab>magentothem</tab>
            <sort_order>142</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <newproductslider_config translate="label">
                    <label>New Product Slider Config</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enabled translate="label comment">
                            <label>Enabled: </label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>
                                adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno
                            </source_model>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                            
                        </enabled>
                        <auto translate="label comment">
                            <label>Auto slide: </label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>
                                adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno
                            </source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                            
                        </auto>
                        <title translate="label">
                            <label>Title: </label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </title>
                        <speed translate="label">
                            <label>Slideshow Speed: </label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>16></sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        </speed>
                        <interval translate="label">
                            <label>Animation Speed:</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>17</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        </interval>
                        <show_price translate="label comment">
                            <label>Show Price: </label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>
                                adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno
                            </source_model>
                            <sort_order>18</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                            
                        </show_price>
                        <addtocart translate="label comment">
                            <label>Show Add To Cart: </label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>
                                adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno
                            </source_model>
                            <sort_order>19</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                            
                        </addtocart>
                        <addtowishlist translate="label comment">
                            <label>Show Add To Wishlist: </label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>
                                adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno
                            </source_model>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                            
                        </addtowishlist>
                        <addtocompare translate="label comment">
                            <label>Show Add To Compare: </label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>
                                adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno
                            </source_model>
                            <sort_order>21</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                            
                        </addtocompare>                 
                        <review translate="label comment">
                            <label>Show Review Rating: </label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>
                                adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno
                            </source_model>
                            <sort_order>22</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                            
                        </review>                       
                        <description translate="label comment">
                            <label>Show Short Description: </label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>
                                adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno
                            </source_model>
                            <sort_order>23</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                            
                        </description>
                        <maxlength translate="label">
                            <label>Short Description Max Length: </label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <comment>Empty for display all short description.</comment>
                            <sort_order>24</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </maxlength>                        
                        <qty translate="label">
                            <label>Qty of Product: </label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>25</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </qty>
                        <items_show translate="label">
                            <label>Number Product Show: </label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>26</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </items_show>
                        <item_width translate="label">
                            <label>Width of Item: </label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>27</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </item_width>   
                        <width_thumbnail translate="label">
                            <label>Width of Thumbnail: </label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>28</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </width_thumbnail>                      
                        <height_thumbnail translate="label">
                            <label>Height of Thumbnail: </label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </height_thumbnail>
                        <next_back translate="label">
                            <label>Show Next/Back control: </label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>
                                adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno
                            </source_model>
                            <sort_order>40</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </next_back>
                        <nav_ctrl translate="label">
                            <label>Show navigation control: </label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>
                                adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno
                            </source_model>
                            <sort_order>42</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </nav_ctrl>                   
                    </fields>
                </newproductslider_config>                      
            </groups>
        </newproductslider>
    </sections>
</config>
```

**Edit**

now i successfully installed theme & i can see all modules configuration, but 2 modules result not displaying in frontend [home page], they are  [ New Product slider, Featured Product slider ]

Comment: Update your sysyem.xml

Comment: @Kothari check updated question....

Comment: In your screen shot where is magento theme tab ?

Comment: @SHPatel under General > web > design, i set the theme......

Comment: First try to logout and login again. If that does not work check under the `System->Permissions->Roles` if your role has access to the `Magentothem` section of the config. If you don't find anything there, post the contents of `etc/adminhtml.xml` in the question.

Comment: @BabyinMagento add adminhtml.xml and config.xml also add etc/modules/Magentothem_Newproductslider.xml

Comment: which magento version you are using ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento For me after the installation all works fine  https://gyazo.com/46821ddc2d3d65d5799e760304244ad8 . Which folder from the archive you are using?

Comment: You can just share your module code so some help will occur.

Comment: @BabyinMagento you want to add all module in one tab `<tab>magentothem</tab>` that are created by main theme

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau Thanks for your time, i tried `ma_aries_quickstart_1.8.0.0.zip` can you please tell what folder you used to install? did you installed fresh magento pack & theme or did you installed both using one folder ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento I used the ma_aries_template_1.2_for_magento_1.8.x.x folder. In it there are 4 folders with different themes. I just copied them to the already installed magento. As far as I see, each module has an own menu item. Here is it for the ["New Product Slider"](https://gyazo.com/67a75073987a3657329270bba3ccfa2b). Perhaps you are looking for some specific menu item?

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau okay , i will try that, also is frontend looking like this : http://demo4plazathemes.com/19/ma_aries/index.php/?___store=russian , also which magento version you used ?

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau you did't used sample database of that theme right ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento Magento ver. 1.9.1.1. I don't use the sample data

Comment: fine @SiarheyUchukhlebau thanks a lot, i will check today night & let you know.....

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau i installed theme succesfully , now i can see all module configuration in backend , but i cant see result of `New product slider` in frontend , but according to [theme link](http://demo4plazathemes.com/19/ma_aries/index.php/?___store=russian) , you can see `new slider in home page`.... same for`featured products` ....

Comment: @BabyinMagento enable your slider in the configuration https://gyazo.com/58b630078cdd863f992b1b3a222b9637 then mark some products as new https://gyazo.com/3fdc8460b82f8774544017236ae5bbd1 (new from ... to date) refresh cache & reindex. You should see result: https://gyazo.com/e7bd10c5f7a260f164fb0cfae9854820

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau  expect `reindex`, i done all other things as you said, i wll try with `reindex` & inform you in night.... Thanks....

Comment: uff, finally ..... i faced some isssue when reindexing, also some files did't copied in filezilla even after i tried many time, later i used cpanel, still `new products` did't displayed, because i installed 1.9.3 & `new product slider` was `whitelisted` , later i solved with help of "ForMat", @SiarheyUchukhlebau please post an answer, i want to accept your answer as you guided i didt installed theme properly & you spent your valuable time to install theme and check the issue.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento I just want to help you as others helps me. Please accept the Raphael's answer as most relevant to the issue.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau yes, Raphael's answer is really fanatstic. i wanted to accept yours because you spent most time, It's really feast for eyes to see your answer ,  i will accept his answer Thanks a lot.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possible reasons a configuration section is not showing:

- **Module is disabled.** Try to check in `app/etc/modules/Magentothem_Newproductslider.xml` that it is enable. If you can't find this file, theme providers some provide one single module configuration (like `Magentothem_All.xml` where every module included in the theme has got its configuration in it.
- **Module output is disabled.** Go to **System > Configuration > Advanced** and ensure that the module output is not disabled for this module.
- The user does not have the permission to access that resource. **Ensure you're viewing the configuration as a full admin** to remove that possible issue from the list of problems. If you can see it as a full admin, **change the role of your normal user to add the module configuration to your allowed resources.**
- Related to the point above, **the module does not have a proper `adminhtml.xml` in it.** This file is used to declare the ACL resources. Sometimes it is merged directly in the `config.xml` you will have to check that.
- You're using compilation and did not recompile. Go to **System > Tools > Compilation** and recompile.
- **Flushing the Magento cache, logging out and logging back in** sometimes help fixing system configuration access issues.
- **Incompatibility with your Magento version / installed modules.** Try to download a fresh install of Magento (same version as the one you're using) and install the theme on it. **If the same problem persists, the module is probably not compatible with this Magento version.** If the problem disappears, that means **it's either an incompatibility with your other modules or a database issue.** To narrow that down, try to **disable all the custom / 3rd party modules installed one by one and refresh the configuration after each time you disable a module to find which module is causing a problem.** If after disabling a module, the configuration section appears that means you've found the module incompatible with the theme. If that still does not work, it's most likely a database issue and you'll have to debug the workflow manually to find the culprit.

Comment: @BabyinMagento you're welcome

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
<tabs>
        <magentothem translate="label" module="newproductslider">
            <label>Magentothem</label>
            <sort_order>205</sort_order>
        </magentothem>
    </tabs>
```

**Change to this**

```
<tabs>
        <newproductslider translate="label" module="newproductslider">
            <label>Magentothem</label>
            <sort_order>205</sort_order>
        </newproductslider>
    </tabs>
```

and section part also

Change to this

```
<sections>
        <magentothem_newproductslider translate="label" module="newproductslider">

</magentothem_newproductslider>
```

Comment: Thanks , but it did't worked for me.....

Comment: Change <tabs> name to this <magentothem_newproductslider> also

Comment: changed it, still not displaying any menu related to custom modules.....

Comment: You have adminhtml.xml in this module or not

Comment: yes i have both adminhtml.xml & config.xml too.....

Comment: No Download optionn

Comment: can you see download button in right side, please click on that....

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an ACL file for these settings?
It should be in etc/adminhtml.xml 
and it should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <admin>
         <children>
            <magentothem translate="title" module="newproductslider">
              <children>
                <newproductslider translate="title">
                <title>New Product Slider settings</title>
                </newproductslider >
              </children>
            </customer>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
<config>
```